# Translating marginal effects for layperson

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients, causality, treatment-effect, marginal-effect

In a setting with a binary outcome logistic model focusing on a binary treatment, how would you translate the average marginal effects to make it understandable to a layperson?

Let’s suppose the treatment X has an AME of -0.025, meaning that the probability that y=1 decreases by 2.5% points when X=1.

Could we say the that, comparing 1000 individuals with X=0 and 1000 with X=1, there will be around 25 people affected by the treatment variable? Is this a correct way to describe the outcome? Any possibile alternative interpretation? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your last interpretation is close, except that an AME doesn't compare two groups of people; it compares the *same* people under two different treatment scenarios. So, you might say

> Giving 1000 people the treatment prevents 25 events on average,
> relative to had they not been given treatment.

The "had they not been" suggests a counterfactual, that is, comparing two situations with the same people under two different scenarios. Something similar might be

> For every 1000 people, we would expect to see about 25 more events if they
> were not treated than if they were.

This latter interpretation emphasizes the urgency of needing to avoid not treating patients and reflects the fact that the AME is interpreted as the effect on the same group of people.

If you didn't do the work to be able to interpret your AME as causal (i.e., you didn't adjust for confounding), then the AME is just a statistical object that has no intuitive meaning for a layperson. It's just the expected conditional risk given treatment minus the expected conditional risk given control.

Comment: Thanks Noah. Perfectly explained. Indeed I adjusted for confounders, and I guess your two potential explanations hold also when the regression equations has controls.

Answer (score 0):

One intuitive phrasing of an AME of -0.025 is "the model estimates that, on average, the treatment decreased the probability of the outcome by 2.5 percentage points"

The key phrase is "on average," because that's the key to how the AME process works. To calculate an AME you (or rather, your stats program) do the following:

1. Look at the first case in the database, and use the logit model to predict the likelihood that y=1 holding x at 0, and holding all other variables at that case's own values (so if you control for gender and that person was female, hold female at "1," if you control for age and the persin is 25, hold age at 25).
2. Then, ask the model to predict the likelihood that y=1 holding all other variables at those same values (i.e. the values of the first case - female=0, age=25) but this time hold x at 1, instead of zero.
3. Subtract the likelihood you got in step 2 from what you got in step 1. This is the "risk difference" for the first case - the change in percentage points of the probability that y=1 associated with getting the treatment - holding all other covariates constant.
4. Repeat steps 1, 2, and 3 for every case in the dataset (or in the subpopulation you ran the model on). Each time you will get an estimated "percentage point change" associated with a particular case
5. Average all those percentage point changes together. That's the AME.

Hence, the AME is the "average" percentage point change in the probability that y=1 associated with the treatment. This whole process is needed because, a given effect size (that is, a particular logit coefficient or odds ratio) will translate into different risk differences ("x percentage points more/less likely) or risk ratios (X percent more/less likely) depending on the baseline probability of experiencing the outcome for people who didn't get the treatment, which depends on the other variables in the model.